# Can a predicative clause be simplified to a gerund structure since both of them could be used as a predicative?

Tags: complementation, content-clauses, gerund-clauses

Can a predicative clause be simplified to a gerund structure 
since both of them could be used as a predicative?
Do "My idea is that the child should be sent to school" and
"My idea is the child being sent to school" mean the same thing?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The most manifest difference between "My idea is **that** the child **should be sent** to school" and "My idea is the child **being** sent to school" is that the latter has lost the modal verb "should" and hence the meaning of obligation has been lost.

Comment: @Nico True; but that *should* may (depending on context) bear a 'subjunctive' rather than a deontic interpretation: "that the child **be** sent" rather than "that the child **ought to be** sent".

Comment: @StoneyB I have another question as an aside. Would it be acceptable to avoid the use of subjunctive and write "My idea is that the child is sent to school"?

Comment: @Nico Some people find that acceptable; I don't.

Answer (score 2):

This is an excellent question—which, alas, has no very clear answer.

You are probably aware that different verbs ‘license’ different sorts of clausal complements: bare infinitive clauses, *to* infinitive clauses, *for* infinitive clauses, *GEN-* and *ACC-* gerund clauses, and *that* finite clauses.

The same thing is true of the sorts of predicative complements which may be attributed to nouns: each noun has its own preferences. And *idea* doesn't really like gerunds very much: gerunds are too “nouny”.

That is: with non-clause phrases *idea* is most comfortable with adjective phrases, including participles, which characterize the idea —*good*, *original*, *ill-considered*, *depraved*, *intriguing* *ground-breaking*. Noun phrases usually show up only when they express a characterization:

> That idea’s a winner!
>   My idea is a novel approach to the problem.

This aversion to noun complements extends to clausal complements. When you speak of an idea as an action, a thing to be done, rather than a characterization, *idea* prefers infinitive and finite phrases, because these have a much “verbier” feel than gerunds.

> My idea is **to send** the child to another school.
>   My idea is **that** we **send** the child to another school.

And if you want to cast the action in the passive you employ either your original construction, with a *that* phrase, or a *for* infinitive clause:

> My idea is **that** the child **be**/**should be** sent to another school.
>   My idea is **for** the child **to be** sent to another school.

Noun clausal complements are like verb clausal complements: they must be learned word-by-word.